# email attachment only works with changed extra_text

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I am trying to send one or more CSV files in my android application. The code works fine and when the gmail app is running, the attachment and all "EXTRAS" like subject, text are available. When I send the email, the email will arrive without attachment.
The e-mail will only be sent correctly (with attachment) if I change at least one letter in the email text/body.
If I remove the EXTRA_TEXT it's the same problem, I have to enter at least one letter manuel in the GMail app.

How you can see at the code, I also tried intent.setType("plain/text")

Here is my code:

```
File filePath = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    File files[] = filePath.listFiles();
    uris = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File file : files){
        if(file.getPath().endsWith(".csv")){
            uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),"com.my.company", file ));
        }
    }
    if(uris.size() > 0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        //intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"myEmail@abc.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "new CSV");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, there is a new CSV file for you");
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending multiple attachments"), REQUEST_EMAIL_CODE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no files available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Thank you for your help